# Series of books about a human that joins an alien army?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Pretty sure I got this one on Kindle Unlimited at some point. Series of books. Starts off with a man in Hawaii with a friend, when a UFO/anomaly of some kind shows up in the sky. They go into the ocean to investigate something that fell. His friend dies from touching the object. MC has some kind of connection to government, some kind of agent maybe? He winds up recruited to be in an alien army? Has adult relations with an anthropomorphic cat woman thing as well, and they use some kind of electrical weapon, a tube with a ball on the end, I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: 2014-2016 I believe. And my guess would be it was newer, probably put out for free thru Kindle, also pretty sure I was able to get the audio books for free with it with Kindle unlimited

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This sounds familiar. Especially the part where the friend dies when he touches it. Could it have been one of the newer GameLit, LitRPG, HaremLit books? Where the Protagonist gradually builds up their skills and abilities. I don't think I have read this, other than maybe a review, or preview.

Comment: @DreadBeard - If you follow the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), you should be able to merge your new account with the one you used to post this question, which will enable you post comments in this thread the normal way, rather than having to edit them into the question.

Comment: LogicDictates, thank you for the helpful link. The book is not gamelit, rpglit, or anything with a progression of skills etc, except for the MC rank.

Comment: After the object in the ocean, he and many others from around the globe are put into an almost hunger games situation where they compete with each other. The fleet that he joins has many different species of aliens all fighting under one banner. The anthropomorphized cats, and I seem to recall a race that was crablike. MC trades in one of his human crewmates for one of the cat species from a rival group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost 100% sure this is *[Rebel Fleet](https://www.goodreads.com/series/193930-rebel-fleet)* by B V Larson.

The MC starts in Maui and is kidnapped to fight in the titular Rebel Fleet where he has to prove himself against other aliens (humans and all these different species of aliens are related somehow) to establish his place amongst them.  He starts a "relationship" with an antropomorphic cat woman.

There's 4 books in total in the series and in later books the MC is more working with Earth governments.

Comment: Spot on. Can't believe I didn't think to check his stories, I just rediscovered his undying mercenaries series which I found at around the same time as this one. Thank you!